# Фильтрация данных в таблице - как правильно организовать

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Изучаю связку Spring+Hibernate
Имеется сущность:

```
public class PersonEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private City city;
    private Countrycountry;
...
}
```

Мне необходимо выполнить фильтрацию. данных в этой таблице, для отображения в окне браузера.
Я думал сделать реализацию в сервисе следующих методов:

```
.findByName(name);
.findByNameAndAge(name, age);
.findByNameAndAge(name, age, city);
.findByNameAndAge(name, city);
...
```

Но че-то получается, слишком дофига вариантов методов.
Как сделать одни универсальный метод, т.е. что-то типа коллекции в которую можно добавить сколько нужно параметров.
Начал читать по этому вопросу и совсем запутался.
Где-то пишут про @Filter,
где-то про Hibernate Search,
есть еще Spring Data Elasticsearch.
Подскажите самый простой и актуальный способ реализации этого. Если есть ссылки на реальные примеры, буду очень признателен.

Dao:

```
public interface PersonDao extends GeneralDAO<PersonEntity>{
    public List<PersonEntity> searchName(String name);
    public List<PersonEntity> searchAllFields(
            String name,
            Integer age,
            City city);
}
```

В GeneralDAO описаны все стандартные методы типа get, save и т.д.
Репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndAgeAndCity(
            String name,
            Integer age,
            City city);
}
```

Сервис:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService implements PersonRepository {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    ...
    описание всех стандартных методов чтения-записи в БД

    @Override
    public List<PersonEntity> searchName(String name) {
        return productTypeRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(name);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PersonEntity> searchAllFields(
            String name,
            Integer age,
            City city) {
        return personRepository.findByNameAndAgeAndCity(
                name,
                age,
                city);
    }
}
```

В контроллере обьявление и вызов:

```
@Autowired
private PersonService personService;
...

personService.searchAllFields(...);
```

Метод searchName прекрасно работает, а вот searchAllFields выдает всегда пустой список, даже если задаю одно имя, остальные = null

Попробовал в сервисе изменить метод:

```
 List<PersonEntity> findByNameIsNullAndAgeIsNullAndCityIsNull
```

На это Spring выдает ошибку:
Error creating bean with name personRepository.
At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте 1 метод и 1 запрос этого достаточно

к примеру:

`.findByPersonNameAndAge(String name, Integer age, String city);`

делаем запрос таким образом, если не даны значение для какого либо параметра, нужно его не фильтровать

```
Select *
From Users
Where (user_name = name or name is null)
and (user_age = age or age is null)
and (user_city = city or city is null)
```

таким образом если у вас будем вызов `.findByPersonNameAndAge(null, 25, null);` тогда выведет всем кто 25 лет

Comment: А можно подробней? У меня что-то так не работает. Т.е. findByName(name) работает, а вот когда вызываю findByNameAndAgeAndCity(name, age, city), где задаю только name, остальное null, то возвращает пустой список. Я в репозитории описываю этот запрос с генерацией по имени, а не на HSQL. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: @alex добавьте ваш код на вопрос, помогу проверить в чем проблема